# Excel Ranking Not Working

Tags: excel, ranking-functions

I am trying to make a list of top 25 based on the rank function in excel, but my list is missing the 11th and 20th value. Upon inspection, I noticed that there are identical values in these spots preventing them from ranking correctly. Is there a way to give each a unique rank? (i.e. John and Sam both have the value 31 and their ranks should be 10th and 11th instead of both being 10th.)

Comment: BTW, I am using excel 2010.

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

[image]

Both Patricia and Mary have the same score, but they need different ranks.  In **C2** enter:

```
=RANK(A2,$A$2:$A$11,0)+COUNTIF($A$2:$A2,A2)-1
```

and copy down:

[image]

This makes ranks that are simple, sequential with no gaps and no dups.

Answer (score 0):

Gary's answer works if you have a list of x people and want x rankings. If you had a list of x people and y rankings, you could use something like:

```
=(COUNTIF($B$2:B2,B2)-1)*0.0001+B2
```

to change the value of the thing to rank to make each person unique, seen here.

[image]

Then, you can put the formula

```
=MATCH(LARGE(C:C,ROW()),C:C,0)
```

in E, copied down how many ever ranks you want and finally

```
=INDIRECT("A"&E2)
```

in F, copied down again how many ranks you want. This returns the name of the person, ranked without duplicates and with any arbitrary number of ranks you want.